# Swift modal view background appearing black after setting it to clear

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to present a custom view from a controller modally, however when I do so the background of everything but the textfield I have turns black as seen in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5vU7.png) . ([the intended modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ageGc.png))

This seems to be a fairly common problem, however I have already implemented the code that most similar questions pose as the answer

here is my addEvent method in the first controller:

```
@IBAction func addEvent(_ sender: Any) {
    let newEventViewController = NewEventViewController()
    newEventViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    newEventViewController.view.isOpaque = false
    navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    navigationController?.present(newEventViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help figuring out what I am missing would be appreciated. If it makes a difference I am creating my app using individual xib files and not a storyboard.

Comment: Can you provide more info? have you tried self.present...? also setting self.modalPresentationStyle
usually the isOpaque and backgroundColor should be set in viewDidLoad but I dont think that is your problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the modalPresentationStyle of newEventController not the navigationController like this:

```
newEventViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
```

Also although not needed I would present from self rather than the navigation controller like this:

```
self.present(newEventViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: saved me! thanks! I was thinking I should add this property the view controller 'viewDidLoad' - which did not work obviously, thanks for the code sample